# Tesseract 4.0.0-beta.1 - Training

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to train tesseract 4.0.0. But when i searched for it, only training for version 3 is seen. Can someone suggest me some blogs that explains tesseract 4.0.0 training.

Answer (score 1):

For training Neural net based LSTM Tesseract 4.0:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00

Comment: + 4.0.0-beta.1 is quite old.